# The tag on feature-scaling says "zero mean" and unit variance. Is it correct?

Tags: normalization, feature-scaling, distribution, normal

The tag on feature scaling says:

> Popular feature scaling types include scaling the data to have zero
> mean and unit variance, and scaling the data between a given minimum
> and maximum value.

It is difficult to understand what is assumption of "zero mean" and unit variance? Could it be explained in terms of scaling?Should not the tag be modified or corrected?

Comment: you can propose an edit to the tag if you want

Comment: shall be glad to take it up. I am trying to grasp  several other terms e.g. normalization, standardization etc. which are probably ill-defined in data-science.

Answer (score 2):

To generate zero mean and unit variance, you are looking at **[standardization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score)**. Where a feature $x$ becomes scaled feature $z$ like this:

$$z = \frac{x - \mu}{\sigma}$$

Where $\mu$ is the mean of that feature and $\sigma$ the standard deviation.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't quite understand what is unclear about my answer. This is a very simple formula and the link I provided has plenty of additional information. I felt that it was better to keep the answer concise and leave the link as extra material for those that are interested to read further

Comment: μ is not mean here. In statistics, it is sum total of deviations from   mean. The sum total is zero under the assumption of normal distribution. For the purpose of so-called scaling, we "standardize" the data (individual observations)with the help of standard deviation of raw data). I guess the tag needs a correction.

Comment: @SubhashC.Davar mu is correctly identified as the mean of the feature here (sample mean, if you like).  The "sum total of deviations from the mean" would be sum(x-mu), which is zero regardless of the feature distribution.  The "-mu" part of the formula centers the data to have zero mean, and the "/sigma" part scales it to have unit variance as the tag description says.  It is perhaps unfortunate that centering and scaling together get called just "feature scaling", but that's now the standard terminology.

Answer (score -1):

Standard Normal Distribution is denoted as N(0,1) and zero is not "zero mean" and it is equal to sum total of deviations of sample means from grand mean of a sampling distribution of means.It does not have any link with "feature scaling type". Further, I do not understand "scaling the data between a given minimum and maximum value." what does it mean in terms of scaling? Therefore,it seems feature scaling tag should be revised.

Comment: "scaling the data between a given minimum and maximum value" refers to the practice of applying a linear transformation so that the end result has range [0, 1], or [-1, 1], or maybe some other given min/max.

Comment: The zero in "N(0,1)" absolutely is the mean of that distribution. In the context of feature scaling, there doesn't have to be a normal distribution involved, nor a collection of samples, just the one sample you've got as a training dataset.

Comment: Am trying to understand scaling and normal Distribution theory. If normal distribution assumption is not relevant , how could scaling types  consider it as a basis for scaling types ?

Comment: scaling theory reflects measurement theory and normal distribution assumption is reflecting  the statistics ?

Comment: There is an unfortunate overloading of the terms "standard" and "normal" (and "regular" and...) in mathematics, which makes this confusing. A few (conflicting!) definitions are given at https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/35591/232706